# Angular 4 - Uncaught Error during WebStorm Debug

Tags: angular

I'm running an Angular 4 app that compile, but when I launch debug with WebStorm I got this message :

```
Uncaught Error
CompileMetadataResolver._reportError    
CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata    
CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata    
CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata  
CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata 
(anonymous function)    
CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata   
CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata 
JitCompiler._loadModules    
JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents 
JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync  
PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone   
PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule    
328 
__webpack_require__ 
702 
__webpack_require__ 
webpackJsonpCallback    
(anonymous function)
```

Last change done was trying to import my APIService into my app.module.ts
there in Github -> https://github.com/Sagenda/Angular4SagendaCalendar

Any idea? I'm new to Angular and this message isn't really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to add `@` fron of `Injectable`. It should be `@Injectable() export class APIService {...`

Comment: First : well done, then stupid question: why is this not thrown at compilation?